# Difference between next.angular.io and angular.io

Tags: angular

I just discovered that there is another Angular documentation site at

https://next.angular.io/docs

The site looks the same as

https://angular.io/docs

Same version, same documentation, etc. Is there a difference? Why is it there?

Comment: They've *just* released 5.1 - `stable` and `next` are currently the same, but presumably it will start to diverge as work on 5.2 continues.

Comment: Only by looking at the URLs you can strongly assume whats the answer to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's the documentation for the next build. At the bottom of the page you can find the different build numbers.